# Data immediately deallocated

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am currently working on a Headline UI Element for my app and I am having an issue with my data being immediately deallocated. I have been trying to get the console to print any data it is receiving, but I am not even seen that in the console. What I am trying to achieve is for the app to connect to its targeted "CDN" and then pull data for the headlines. Using PHP I am preforming a SQL Query to generate an array that the app will then feed off of. When running said scrip the following array is generated.

```
{"id":"1","title":"Meet ergoWare","header_image":"https://gba.ergoware.io/cache/content/topstory/ergo_news_01.svg","summary":"GBA's New Ergonomic Portal!"}
```

Stunning array yeah, so the next part is it will then be read and compiled in the app to create headline cards, but the issue is I cannot get the data to to load. I know there is something I am missing, but without the compiler pointing me in the direction I need, I'm fumbling around with it. So here is the Swift code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var header_image: String
    var summary: String
}

struct HeadlineUI: View {
    @State var results = [Article]()
    var CDNLink: String

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {

            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(results) { result in
                    CardView(image: result.header_image, summary: result.summary, heading: result.title)
                }
                .onAppear(perform: { self.loadData() })
            }
        }
    }

    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: CDNLink) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                        print(self.results)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct HeadlineUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HeadlineUI(CDNLink: "https://gba.ergoware.io/cdn?funct=fetchNews")
    }
}
```

So what should happen is that it connects to the "CDN" and reads the array. That information then is plugged in and for each index of the results, defined by the id, a card should display with the top story image, article header and a short summary. I am starting to get a little more comfortable with Swift, but little hiccups like this keeps breaking my confidence down haha. Thanks for any teachable moments you can provide.

Comment: Change `try? JSONDecoder()` to `try! JSONDecoder()` and you will see the error

Comment: Also, the JSON you posted is an object, not an array, and what your Swift code expects is an object with a property `results`

Comment: @zaitsman Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Response' is the error I got.

Comment: Well yes, that's an obvious one, you have to also remove your `if let ={}` if you're switching to `try!`, just remove `if` and the `{}` after the if statement.

Comment: @zaitsman changing to to what you have recommended ```try! JSONDecoder.decode(Response.self, from:data)``` results with the compiler error Result of call to 'decode(_:from:)' is unused

Comment: Change the code like so:
```
if let data = data {
 let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) 
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                        print(self.results)
                    }
}
```

Comment: @zaitsman on ```decodedResponse.results``` the compiler says: Expression of type '[Article]' is unused

Comment: That's a warnign though, right? not an error? so you should be able to build and run

Comment: @zaitsman yes, but the content is still not either showing and the debug line is not showing me any errors.

Comment: Try replacing `self.results = decodedResponse.results` with `self.results.removeAll();self.results.append(contentsOf: decodedResponse.results)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208677/discussion-between-thealexvond-and-zaitsman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, follow these steps:

1. According to your class **Response**, your service should return this JSON:

   ```
   {
   "results" : [{
      "id":1,
      "title":"Meet ergoWare",
      "header_image":"https://gba.ergoware.io/cache/content/topstory/ergo_news_01.svg",
      "summary":"GBA's New Ergonomic Portal!"
   }]
   }
   ```

   Give it a try using this [url](https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e585d202f00000205961ec9)
2. You should place **.onAppear** in your **HStack** not in your ForEach. Here is a the full example:

   ```
   struct Response: Codable {
       var results: [Article]
   }

   struct Article: Codable, Identifiable {
       var id: Int
       var title: String
       var header_image: String
       var summary: String
   }

   struct HeadlineUI: View {
   @State var results = [Article]()
   var CDNLink: String

   var body: some View {
       ScrollView(.horizontal) {
           HStack(spacing: 20) {
               Text("Response:")
               ForEach(results) { result in
                   Text(result.title)
               }

           }.onAppear(perform: { self.loadData() })
       }
   }

   func loadData() {
       guard let url = URL(string: CDNLink) else {
           print("Invalid URL")
           return
       }
       let request = URLRequest(url: url)

       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
           if error != nil {
               print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
               return
           } else {
               do {
                   let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
                   print(decodedResponse)
                   self.results = decodedResponse.results
               } catch let err {
                   print("Error parsing: \(err)")

               }
           }
       }.resume()
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: So I tried compiling this an I am still not getting any results populating in the UI or the console.

Comment: Can you see an the error in the log? Is your service returning the right JSON? try using this url: https://www.mocky.io/v2/5e585d202f00000205961ec9

Comment: I can't, that's been my issue is I am not getting a single error in my console logs.

Comment: This code works perfectly for me, try restarting reconnecting your devices to restart the console and make sure that your service returns the JSON that your code is expecting otherwise JSONDecoder() will fail

Comment: Wil do, will report back

Comment: so I am testing it out and it appears to be semi working, what is happening currently is that the card is only showing when a segue happens... let me see if I can get a sample recording of it

Comment: http://prnt.sc/r8rqqd <- That is what's happening... it does not make any sense...